# Where do the files inside MS Team private channels got stored

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

When we create public channels inside MS team, as follow:-

[image]

a new folder will be created inside sharepoint document library.

but if we create private channels inside MS team, as follow:-

[image]

now new folders will be created.. so my question is ; Where do the files inside MS Team private channels got stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored on a separate SharePoint Online site dedicated to the private channel.

[Private channel SharePoint sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/MicrosoftTeams/private-channels#private-channel-sharepoint-sites)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i accessed the sharepoint site list using Office 365 admin, but i can not see any site created today..is the sharepoint site which get created for the private channel hidden?

Comment: You can find it via PowerShell. `Get-SPOSite -Limit All -Template TEAMCHANNEL#0`

Comment: so this site will not be shown inside the admin center UI?

Comment: That's correct. The only way to view it is with PowerShell (or APIs).